# Filter by combination of three columns the n first values

Tags: pandas

I have a sorted Dataframe with 4 columns as below. I am trying to filter my dataframe such that for each combination of (Var1, Var2, Var3) I keep the  2 first disctint values for Var4.
For example, the first combination of (Var1, Var2, Var3) that I have in my Dataframe is (A, B, C). The two first distinct values for this combination are value_1 and value_2.
The second combination of (Var1, Var2, Var3) is (A, C, C). I have only one type of value for this combination which is value_14.
Etc...

Input:

```
       Var1  Var2  Var3  Var4
    1     A    B      C  value_1
    2     A    B      C  value_1
    3     A    B      C  value_1
    4     A    B      C  value_1
    5     A    B      C  value_2
    6     A    B      C  value_2
    7     A    B      C  value_3
    8     A    B      C  value_3
    9     A    B      C  value_3
    10    A    B      C  value_4
   11     A    C      C  value_14
   12     A    C      C  value_14
   13     A    C      C  value_14
   14     A    C      C  value_14
   15     B    B      C  value_21
   16     B    B      C  value_21
   17     B    B      C  value_32
   18     B    B      C  value_32
   19     B    B      C  value_33
   20     B    B      C  value_43
```

Output:

```
       Var1  Var2  Var3  Var4
    1     A    B      C  value_1
    2     A    B      C  value_1
    3     A    B      C  value_1
    4     A    B      C  value_1
    5     A    B      C  value_2
    6     A    B      C  value_2
   11     A    C      C  value_14
   12     A    C      C  value_14
   13     A    C      C  value_14
   14     A    C      C  value_14
   15     B    B      C  value_21
   16     B    B      C  value_21
   17     B    B      C  value_32
   18     B    B      C  value_32
```

Note my dataframe is has 5 million rows. I have found a solution using a loop so far but it takes almost an hour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can using

```
df[df.groupby(['Var1','Var2','Var3'])['Var4'].apply(lambda x : x.groupby(x).ngroup()<2)]

Out[106]: 
   Var1 Var2 Var3      Var4
1     A    B    C   value_1
2     A    B    C   value_1
3     A    B    C   value_1
4     A    B    C   value_1
5     A    B    C   value_2
6     A    B    C   value_2
11    A    C    C  value_14
12    A    C    C  value_14
13    A    C    C  value_14
14    A    C    C  value_14
15    B    B    C  value_21
16    B    B    C  value_21
17    B    B    C  value_32
18    B    B    C  value_32
```

Answer (score 3):

`ngroup` labels the group, then we ensure every group begins at 0 by subtracting the min. Then a simple mask.

```
s = df.groupby([*df], sort=False).ngroup()  #sort = False keeps ordering of Val4
s = s - s.groupby([df.Var1, df.Var2, df.Var3]).transform('min')

df[s.le(1)]
```

---

```
   Var1 Var2 Var3      Var4
1     A    B    C   value_1
2     A    B    C   value_1
3     A    B    C   value_1
4     A    B    C   value_1
5     A    B    C   value_2
6     A    B    C   value_2
11    A    C    C  value_14
12    A    C    C  value_14
13    A    C    C  value_14
14    A    C    C  value_14
15    B    B    C  value_21
16    B    B    C  value_21
17    B    B    C  value_32
18    B    B    C  value_32
```

Answer (score 0):

Let use this method:

```
df.drop_duplicates(['Var1','Var2','Var3','Var4'])\
  .groupby(['Var1','Var2','Var3']).head(2)\
  .merge(df, on=['Var1','Var2','Var3','Var4'])
```

Output:

```
   Var1 Var2 Var3      Var4
0     A    B    C   value_1
1     A    B    C   value_1
2     A    B    C   value_1
3     A    B    C   value_1
4     A    B    C   value_2
5     A    B    C   value_2
6     A    C    C  value_14
7     A    C    C  value_14
8     A    C    C  value_14
9     A    C    C  value_14
10    B    B    C  value_21
11    B    B    C  value_21
12    B    B    C  value_32
13    B    B    C  value_32
```

Comment: Not sure if this will be faster for your dataset or not.